# Query "the number of row"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
query = "select c.idEmp, c.idEtat, c.idNiveauValidation," & _
      " c.niveauDejaValider ,T.idTypeD , " & _
       "s.idEmp , s.idNiveauValidation ,s.niveauDejaValider " & _
       " from TypeDemande T " & _
      "INNER JOIN DemandeConge c on c.idTypeD = T.idTypeD " & _
      "INNER JOIN DemandeSalaire s on s.idTypeD = T.idTypeD " & _
      "WHERE (c.idTypeD= " & ddlTypeDemande.SelectedValue & " ) OR ( s.idTypeD=" & ddlTypeDemande.SelectedValue & ")"

sqlCon.Open()

Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
Dim sqlAdap As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dt As New DataTable

sqlAdap.Fill(ds, "TypeDemande")
dt = ds.Tables("TypeDemande")

Dim n As Integer
n = dt.Rows.Count
If n > 0 Then
```

the number of row return is always "0"

Comment: Which language is that? You should add another tag.

Comment: Looks like VB to me...

Comment: Why you have tagged the post by mysql, mysqli with code where user ms sql server client.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `INNER JOINS`, you won't get any records if there aren't corresponding rows in all three tables.

In other words, if either of the tables DemandeConge and DemandeSalaire have missing data that match what you are selecting, you'll get 0 rows returned.

To check this, try changing the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` and see if your data appear.